# DirectX window flickers rapidly with multi-windows and multi-threading

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, graphics, directx

I'm trying to create a basic DirectX based C++ Windows app which can display two images on two separate windows. I am easily able to display a single image. However, I must use multi threading - one thread per window - as it is critical the contents of the windows are updated simultaneously.

At the moment however, I'm just focused on implementing multi threading for two static images, one image per thread per window. The problem I'm having however is that both windows flicker somewhat rapidly / randomly (they flicker to black mostly, occasionally green).

I suspect it may have something to do with the way I combined multi threading with DirectX, as as far as I know mutexes must be used so there isn't simultaneous calls to the device or context. Because of this, I suspect that when the windows re-render, they're contents are blocked by the other thread for some portion of the time.

However, I'm not sure if this is the case or not, and if so, I have no idea how to fix it.

Here is the main game loop:

```cpp
//
// Game.cpp
//

#include "pch.h"
#include "Game.h"
#include <synchapi.h>

extern void ExitGame();

using namespace DirectX;

using Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr;

ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> textures[4];

Game::Game() noexcept(false)
{
    m_deviceResources = std::make_unique<DX::DeviceResources>(DXGI_FORMAT_R10G10B10A2_UNORM,
        DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT, 2, D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0, DX::DeviceResources::c_EnableHDR);
    m_deviceResources->RegisterDeviceNotify(this);

    m_hdrScene[0] = std::make_unique<DX::RenderTexture>(DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_FLOAT);
    m_hdrScene[1] = std::make_unique<DX::RenderTexture>(DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_FLOAT);

}

// Initialize the Direct3D resources required to run.
void Game::Initialize(HWND windows[], int width, int height)
{

    m_deviceResources->SetWindow(0, windows[0], width, height);
    m_deviceResources->SetWindow(1, windows[1], width, height);

    m_deviceResources->CreateDeviceResources();
    CreateDeviceDependentResources();

    m_deviceResources->CreateWindowSizeDependentResources(0);
    m_deviceResources->CreateWindowSizeDependentResources(1);


    CreateWindowSizeDependentResources();

    // TODO: Change the timer settings if you want something other than the default variable timestep mode.
    // e.g. for 60 FPS fixed timestep update logic, call:

    m_timer.SetFixedTimeStep(true);
    m_timer.SetTargetElapsedSeconds(1.0 / 60);

}


void Game::CreateThreads()
{
    std::thread one(&Game::Render, this, 0);
    std::thread two(&Game::Render, this, 1);

    one.join();
    two.join();
}

#pragma region Frame Update
// Executes the basic game loop.
void Game::Tick()
{
    m_timer.Tick([&]() { Update(m_timer); });

    CreateThreads();
}


// Updates the world.
void Game::Update(DX::StepTimer const& timer)
{
    float elapsedTime = float(timer.GetElapsedSeconds());

    char buff[128] = {};
    sprintf_s(buff, "%f\n", elapsedTime);
    OutputDebugStringA(buff);



    // TODO: Add your game logic here.

}
#pragma endregion

std::mutex mut;

#pragma region Frame Render
// Draws the scene.
void Game::Render(int i)
{
    // Don't try to render anything before the first Update.
    if (m_timer.GetFrameCount() == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    mut.lock();

    Clear(i);


    m_deviceResources->PIXBeginEvent(L"Render");
    auto context = m_deviceResources->GetD3DDeviceContext();
    m_spriteBatch = std::make_unique<SpriteBatch>(context);

    mut.unlock();

    // TODO: Add your rendering code here.

    D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC desc2 = { };
    desc2.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_UNORM;
    desc2.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    desc2.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;

    ComPtr<ID3D11ShaderResourceView> shaderResourceView;


    mut.lock();

    auto hr = m_deviceResources->m_d3dDevice->CreateShaderResourceView(
        textures[i].Get(),
        &desc2,
        shaderResourceView.GetAddressOf()
    );

    try {
        m_spriteBatch->Begin();
        m_spriteBatch->Draw(shaderResourceView.Get(), XMFLOAT2(0, 0));
        m_spriteBatch->End();
    } catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        auto msg = e.what();
        throw std::exception(msg);
    }

    m_deviceResources->PIXEndEvent();



    auto renderTarget = m_deviceResources->GetRenderTargetView(i);
    context->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &renderTarget, nullptr);

    mut.unlock();

    m_toneMap[i]->SetOperator(ToneMapPostProcess::None);
        m_toneMap[i]->SetTransferFunction(ToneMapPostProcess::ST2084);
        m_toneMap[i]->SetST2084Parameter(10000.f);

    mut.lock();
    m_toneMap[i]->Process(context);

    ID3D11ShaderResourceView* nullsrv[] = { nullptr };
    context->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, nullsrv);

    mut.unlock();


    // Show the new frame.
    m_deviceResources->Present(i);
}

// Helper method to clear the back buffers.
void Game::Clear(int i)
{
    m_deviceResources->PIXBeginEvent(L"Clear");

    // Clear the views.
    auto context = m_deviceResources->GetD3DDeviceContext();

    auto renderTarget = m_hdrScene[i]->GetRenderTargetView();
    auto depthStencil = m_deviceResources->GetDepthStencilView();

    XMVECTORF32 color;
    auto actual = FXMVECTOR({ {0, 0, 0, 0} });
    color.v = XMColorSRGBToRGB(actual);
    context->ClearRenderTargetView(renderTarget, color);


    context->ClearDepthStencilView(depthStencil, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH | D3D11_CLEAR_STENCIL, 1.0f, 0);
    context->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &renderTarget, depthStencil);

    // Set the viewport.
    auto viewport = m_deviceResources->GetScreenViewport();
    context->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);

    m_deviceResources->PIXEndEvent();
}
#pragma endregion

void Game::OnWindowMoved()
{
    auto r = m_deviceResources->GetOutputSize();
    m_deviceResources->WindowSizeChanged(0, r.right, r.bottom);
    m_deviceResources->WindowSizeChanged(1, r.right, r.bottom);
}

void Game::OnWindowSizeChanged(int index, int width, int height)
{
    if (!m_deviceResources->WindowSizeChanged(index, width, height))
        return;

    CreateWindowSizeDependentResources();

    // TODO: Game window is being resized.
}

// Properties
void Game::GetDefaultSize(int& width, int& height) const
{
    // TODO: Change to desired default window size (note minimum size is 320x200).
    width = 800;
    height = 600;
}

#pragma region Direct3D Resources
// These are the resources that depend on the device.
void Game::CreateDeviceDependentResources()
{
    auto device = m_deviceResources->GetD3DDevice();
    cv::directx::ocl::initializeContextFromD3D11Device(device);


    // TODO: Initialize device dependent objects here (independent of window size).

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        m_hdrScene[i]->SetDevice(device);
        m_toneMap[i] = std::make_unique<ToneMapPostProcess>(device);

        m_toneMap[i]->SetOperator(ToneMapPostProcess::None);
        m_toneMap[i]->SetTransferFunction(ToneMapPostProcess::ST2084);

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        textures[i] = this->getImagesAsTextures()[i];
    }
}

// Allocate all memory resources that change on a window SizeChanged event.
void Game::CreateWindowSizeDependentResources()
{
    auto size = m_deviceResources->GetOutputSize();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        m_hdrScene[i]->SetWindow(size);

        m_toneMap[i]->SetHDRSourceTexture(m_hdrScene[i]->GetShaderResourceView());
    }
}

void Game::OnDeviceLost()
{
    // TODO: Add Direct3D resource cleanup here.


    m_hdrScene[0]->ReleaseDevice();
    m_hdrScene[1]->ReleaseDevice();

    m_toneMap[0].reset();
    m_toneMap[1].reset();
}

void Game::OnDeviceRestored()
{
    CreateDeviceDependentResources();

    CreateWindowSizeDependentResources();
    CreateWindowSizeDependentResources();

}
#pragma endregion
```

I also get this warning, however I'm not sure what it means: `D3D11 WARNING: ID3D11DeviceContext::DrawIndexed: The Pixel Shader expects a Render Target View bound to slot 0, but none is bound. This is OK, as writes of an unbound Render Target View are discarded. It is also possible the developer knows the data will not be used anyway. This is only a problem if the developer actually intended to bind a Render Target View here. [ EXECUTION WARNING #3146081: DEVICE_DRAW_RENDERTARGETVIEW_NOT_SET]`

This code is mostly based on the DirectXTK Win32 template. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple manual mutex lock / unlock during rendering procedure make whole synchronization pointless. There are no simultaneous calls to device or context, but rendering pipeline can be modified from the different threads. For example after `lock` `OMSetRenderTargets` `unlock` another thread may get the lock and set different render target leaving first one with discarded content presented on the screen.